# What is the CMD command for nats-server inside Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, microservices, nestjs, nats.io

I am currently building an application using **NestJS** by following microservice architecture. And use **NATS** as a messaging system. It works fine on my local machine but I am unable to dockerized the NATS server.

The folder structure of my project:

```
├─── services/
    ├─── nats/
    |       Dockerfile
    ├─── client/
    |       ...
    |       ...
    |       .dockerignore
    |       Dockerfile
    └─── docker-compose.yml
```

Now, the `Dockerfile` inside `nats/` folder describes as below:

```
FROM nats:2.1.9

EXPOSE 4222

CMD [ "nats-server" ]
```

And `Dockerfile` inside `client/` folder describes as:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /myProject/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8081

CMD [ "node", "dist/main" ]
```

And the `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nats-server:
    image: nats:2.1.9
    restart: always
    build: ./nats
    ports:
      - 4222:4222

  client-service:
    build: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/myProject/src/app
    depends_on:
      - nats-server
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 8081:3000
```

I've run the command **sudo docker-compose build** and found no error, after that run the command **sudo docker-compose up** and found the following error:

```
Recreating services_nats-server_1 ... done
Recreating services_client-service_1 ... done
Attaching to services_nats-server_1, services_client-service_1
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
services_nats-server_1 exited with code 1
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
client-service_1  | [Nest] 1   - 12/03/2020, 4:44:34 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
client-service_1  | [Nest] 1   - 12/03/2020, 4:44:34 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +41ms
client-service_1  | [Nest] 1   - 12/03/2020, 4:44:34 PM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +1ms
client-service_1  | [Nest] 1   - 12/03/2020, 4:44:34 PM   [InstanceLoader] ClientsModule dependencies initialized +1ms
client-service_1  | [Nest] 1   - 12/03/2020, 4:44:34 PM   [InstanceLoader] ClientsModule dependencies initialized +0ms
client-service_1  | [Nest] 1   - 12/03/2020, 4:44:34 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
client-service_1  | [Nest] 1   - 12/03/2020, 4:44:34 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
services_nats-server_1 exited with code 1
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
nats-server_1     | nats-server: unrecognized command: "nats-server_1"
```

There is no problem with the client service Dockerfile, as it depends on the nats-server tried to run it first. Can anyone please help me to figure out the problem?

I would like to thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `build:` command for the `nats-server` service has overwritten the Docker Hub image. I just need to pull the image and expose the port.

So, my `docker-compose.yml` file will be as following:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nats-server:
    image: nats:2.1.9
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4222:4222

  client-service:
    build: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/myProject/src/app
    depends_on:
      - nats-server
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 8081:3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nats/library/nats/2.1.9/images/sha256-679524b91e0a1e4b983d20d70f7a1495f1c16247cf568f29cbf88f5c4b25e914?context=explore) and you'll notice that `ENTRYPOINT` is set to `/nats-server` and `CMD` is the parameters to `ENTRYPOINT` (`--config nats-server.conf` in that case).
Unless you extend the nats image you don't need to build a new one based on it (remove `build: ./nats` from the compose file). Overriding the default `CMD` can be achieved by setting [`command:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) on the `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: (That combination of `build:` and `image:` will also overwrite the Docker Hub image with your modified one; manually `docker pull nats:2.1.9` will cause Docker to re-fetch the official one.)

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right. `build:` can't be used.